# No cancel button for commenting

Tags: feature-request, comments

If you start writing a comment, and then decide not to, there is no cancel button.  To get rid of the box to write the comment in, you have to reload the page.  It would be better in my opinion if there was a discard button as there is when you ask a question.

Comment: Just don't submit it....

Comment: Just live with the box. Select all and delete or reload the page or close the tab or whatever. As Braiam said, if you don't want to submit, then don't. I really don't see any point in cluttering up the interface with such a needless button.

Comment: Perhaps it could be designed to just disappear again if you click outside of it when it's empty. Just a thought.